# how to add a background image in a panel heading in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i was trying to set a background image in a panel heading in my bootstrap project, but the background image didnt appear. here is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading default" style="background-image:url('img/pheading.jpg');">
     <h4>.....</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">.....
```

Comment: Impossible to reproduce with the code given. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/0eske3qr/ Maybe other problem like overriding of CSS?

Comment: are you absolutely certain the path to your image is correct? sometimes I get that wrong.

Comment: can you replace the url with 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/' ?